# Как выполнить презентацию программ Python, имеющих графический выход

Tags: python

Добрый день !

Вопрос в поиске программ презентации кодов Python по аналогии с Matlab. 
Возможно нужно искать со слово "научный".

MatLab в режиме презентации на автомате выдает красивые тексты доступные для публикации с целью обучения, сопровождения, применения в других разработках и понимания как все работает.

В MatLab есть комментарии, а есть двойные комментарии которые идут как наименование раздела и собираются в оглавление.
Если идет печать значений и графики на экран, они приводятся в презентации вместе с кодом.

Современные требования к тестам предполагают режим "Скрыть/Показать", "+/-" для облегчения восприятия.

На Python наглядный текст получился только с захватом экрана.
Например окно Компас, слева графика, справа две панельки Python с информацией.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

def skr(nomm_):
    time.sleep (3)   
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    im='d:\screenshot'+nomm_+'.png'
    screen.save(im,'PNG')

skr ("Duga 30 10 25")
```

Приходится ждать пока на экране появится графика, или останавливаться перед захватом, чтобы поправить положение графики, выбрать на панельке кода Python, что отображать и нажать "F5"

[image: Пример презентации MatLab]

[image: Пример презентации Python]

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: Вопрос в отсутствии программы для презентаций программ Python по аналогии с MatLab

Comment: Это не вопрос, а утверждение.

Comment: @Vitaly, скорее всего то что вам нужно - ipython notebook: http://ipython.org/notebook.html

Comment: Спасибо за хорошую программу, и Сайт у Вас тоже хороший !

Comment: @VitalyLysanov: спасибо за высокую оценку. Когда у вас будет время, прочитайте пожалуйста раздел справки: [ask]. Он поможет вам в будущем задавать более точные и понятные вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я вас понял, вам нужен [ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)

По сути это тот же REPL, но редактируемый, запускающийся в браузере, причем вывод команды может иметь, например, вид диаграммы matplotlib, формулы LaTeX и т.д. Также можно вставлять заголовки и писать заметки в виде Markdown.

Готовый "ноутбук" можно экспортировать в форматы html, pdf, reST и просто py.

Как это выглядит:
[image: ipython notebook]

Под Windows проще всего установить, скачав и установив пакет Anaconda: http://continuum.io/downloads

Я лично ставил под Windows вручную, но это потребовало некоторых плясок с бубном.

Под Linux вручную ставится абсолютно без проблем, вот например инструкция по установке под Ubuntu: http://koldunov.net/?p=696